# Custom Cursor that invert colors

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, mouse-cursor

I have a question.
How can I make a cursor that revert the color behind it and apply to itself.

Just like a "negative" effect.

But I need that is be automatically without coding each colors, so it can interact with any elements behind itself.

Here is my start for the custom cursor and an exemple of what my background can be:

```js
(function () {
  var follower, init, mouseX, mouseY, positionElement, printout, timer;

  follower = document.getElementById('follower');

  printout = document.getElementById('printout');

  mouseX = event => {
    return event.clientX;
  };

  mouseY = event => {
    return event.clientY;
  };

  positionElement = event => {
    var mouse;
    mouse = {
      x: mouseX(event),
      y: mouseY(event) };

    follower.style.top = mouse.y + 'px';
    return follower.style.left = mouse.x + 'px';
  };

  timer = false;

  window.onmousemove = init = event => {
    var _event;
    _event = event;
    return timer = setTimeout(() => {
      return positionElement(_event);
    }, 1);
  };

}).call(this);

//# sourceURL=coffeescript
```

```css
* {
  cursor: none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.img{
  width:49vw;
  height:99vh;
  position:absolute;
  background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/531880/pexels-photo-531880.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=1000');
}
.img2{
  width:49vw;
  height:99vh;
  left:49vw;
  position:absolute;
  background: url('https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/0*I-sI3u34g0ydRqyA');
}

#follower {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
#follower #circle {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 1.5em;
  width: 1.5em;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
  margin-left: -0.5em;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div id="follower">
  <div id="circle"></div>
</div>

<div class="img"></div>
<div class="img2"></div>
```

How can I give the cursor a negative effect?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is an idea using background where the trick is to simulate the cursor using a `radial-gradient` so you can define the color on each element like you want:

```js
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
  document.body.style.setProperty('--x',(e.clientX)+'px');
  document.body.style.setProperty('--y',(e.clientY)+'px');
  
}
```

```css
* {
  cursor: none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.red{
  width:33vw;
  height:100vh;
  position:absolute;
  background:
  radial-gradient(farthest-side ,white 95%,transparent 100%)
    calc(var(--x) - .75em) calc(var(--y) - .75em)/ /*position*/
    1.5em 1.5em   /*size of circle*/
    fixed no-repeat;
  background-color:red;
}
.black{
  width:33vw;
  height:100vh;
  margin-left:33vw;
  position:absolute;
  background:radial-gradient(farthest-side ,cyan 95%,transparent 100%)
    calc(var(--x) - .75em) calc(var(--y) - .75em)/1.5em 1.5em  fixed no-repeat;
  background-color:black;
}
.green{
  width:33vw;
  height:100vh;
  margin-left:66vw;
  position:absolute;
  background:radial-gradient(farthest-side ,blue 95%,transparent 100%)
    calc(var(--x) - .75em) calc(var(--y) - .75em)/1.5em 1.5em  fixed no-repeat;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
```

The trick is that each gradient is made `fixed` so it is positionned relatively to the viewport then I use the same CSS variable for all the gradient to place them in the same position. Each one will be visible only in its section.

In case you will have content and you need to the cursor above everything, you can consider pseudo element to create the layer on the top:

```js
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
  document.body.style.setProperty('--x',(e.clientX)+'px');
  document.body.style.setProperty('--y',(e.clientY)+'px');
  
}
```

```css
* {
  cursor: none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.box {
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  color:#fff;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:999;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0; 
  background:
  radial-gradient(farthest-side ,var(--c) 95%,transparent 100%)
    calc(var(--x) - .75em) calc(var(--y) - .75em)/1.5em 1.5em  fixed no-repeat;
}


.red{
  width:33vw;
  height:100vh;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:red;
  --c:white;
}
.black{
  width:33vw;
  height:100vh;
  margin-left:33vw;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:black;
  --c:cyan;
}
.green{
  width:33vw;
  height:100vh;
  margin-left:66vw;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:green;
  --c:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="red box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin molestie sem non dui tempus placerat non ut nulla. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In vel nulla commodo, dignissim sem in, viverra ipsum. Nam non libero neque.</div>
<div class="black box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin molestie sem non dui tempus placerat non ut nulla. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In vel nulla commodo, dignissim sem in, viverra ipsum. Nam non libero neque.</div>
<div class="green box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin molestie sem non dui tempus placerat non ut nulla. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In vel nulla commodo, dignissim sem in, viverra ipsum. Nam non libero neque.</div>
```

---

Here is another idea where you can color the cursor you made with a `linear-gradient` having the same dimension as your 3 sections:

```js
(function () {
  var follower, init, mouseX, mouseY, positionElement, printout, timer;

  follower = document.getElementById('follower');

  printout = document.getElementById('printout');

  mouseX = event => {
    return event.clientX;
  };

  mouseY = event => {
    return event.clientY;
  };

  positionElement = event => {
    var mouse;
    mouse = {
      x: mouseX(event),
      y: mouseY(event) };

    follower.style.top = mouse.y + 'px';
    return follower.style.left = mouse.x + 'px';
  };

  timer = false;

  window.onmousemove = init = event => {
    var _event;
    _event = event;
    return timer = setTimeout(() => {
      return positionElement(_event);
    }, 1);
  };

}).call(this);

//# sourceURL=coffeescript
```

```css
* {
  cursor: none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.red{
  width:33vw;
  height:100vh;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:red;
}
.black{
  width:33vw;
  height:100vh;
  margin-left:33vw;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:black;
}
.green{
  width:33vw;
  height:100vh;
  margin-left:66vw;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:green;
}

#follower {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
#follower #circle {
  position: absolute;
  background:
    linear-gradient(white,white) 0  0,
    linear-gradient(cyan,cyan) 33vw 0,
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) 66vw 0;
  background-size:33vw 100vh;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 1.5em;
  width: 1.5em;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
  margin-left: -0.5em;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div id="follower">
  <div id="circle"></div>
</div>

<div class="red"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
```

relevant part of the above code:

```
 background:
    linear-gradient(white,white) 0  0,
    linear-gradient(cyan,cyan) 33vw 0,
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) 66vw 0;
 background-size:33vw 100vh;
 background-attachment:fixed;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your new requirements, you can consider [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) to achieve what you want

```js
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
  document.body.style.setProperty('--x',(e.clientX)+'px');
  document.body.style.setProperty('--y',(e.clientY)+'px');
  
}
```

```css
* {
  cursor: none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.box {
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  color:#fff;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:999;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0; 
  background:
  radial-gradient(farthest-side ,#fff 95%,transparent 100%)
    calc(var(--x) - .75em) calc(var(--y) - .75em)/1.5em 1.5em  fixed no-repeat;
  mix-blend-mode:difference;
}


.red{
  width:33vw;
  height:100vh;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:red;
}
.black{
  width:33vw;
  height:100vh;
  margin-left:33vw;
  position:absolute;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/800/600?image=1069) center/cover;
}
.green{
  width:33vw;
  height:100vh;
  margin-left:66vw;
  position:absolute;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/800/600?image=1039) center/cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="red box"></div>
<div class="black box"></div>
<div class="green box"></div>
```

You simply need to change the cursor color (once) and define the blending mode you want.

Here is with the cursor element:

```js
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
  document.body.style.setProperty('--x',(e.clientX)+'px');
  document.body.style.setProperty('--y',(e.clientY)+'px');
  
}
```

```css
* {
  cursor: none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
body:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:999;
  top:var(--y);
  left:var(--x);
  right:0;
  bottom:0; 
  width:1.5em;
  height:1.5em;
  border-radius:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  background:#fff;
  mix-blend-mode:difference;
}


.red{
  width:33vw;
  height:100vh;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:red;
}
.black{
  width:33vw;
  height:100vh;
  margin-left:33vw;
  position:absolute;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/800/600?image=1069) center/cover;
}
.green{
  width:33vw;
  height:100vh;
  margin-left:66vw;
  position:absolute;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/800/600?image=1039) center/cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="red box"></div>
<div class="black box"></div>
<div class="green box"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer.It will help me with my others projects but i need to do it dynamically because i have images on my website. The code that i propose is just an exemple but any code are good to me, i just want that the cursor became a circle that reverse the color behind it

Comment: @TutOzz can you be more precise on the *dynamic part* you want?

Comment: I edited my code in the first post for a better comprehansion. I need that the circle act like a negative filter, and i can't just code each colors because i have images and a lot of elements in my page. The cursor need to be visible anywhere, so i just want it to apply "negative" effect. So, the code you answered me is correct but i need a method to do it automatically and on images

Comment: @TutOzz check the last udpdate

Comment: If you use an element for your cursor, make sure you use  `pointer-events: none` so it doesn't block clicks or hover events from other elements

Comment: I tried following this but the cursor is always drawn way above my actual mouse position. EDIT: it's based off of the scroll position on the body. How do I counteract this?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Temani Afif's answer:

His code breaks if you have to scroll, as the drawn cursor location is off from the actual cursor location by the amount you've scrolled.

You could just add `document.documentElement.scrollTop` to the y value, but then the cursor isn't updated on scroll.

You could call the function to update the `--x` and `--y` properties `onscroll` in addition to `onmousemove`, however, the `onscroll` event doesn't have an `e.clientX` or `e.clientY`, so those values are calculated as 0 and the cursor position is way off.

In order to solve this, I am caching the x and y values from then latest mouse move, then updating the properties on both mouse move and on scroll with a function that uses the cached x and y values and adds the `scrollTop` to the y value:

```js
let x, y;

document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    x = e.clientX;
    y = e.clientY;
    updateProps();
};

document.onscroll = updateProps;

function updateProps() {
    document.body.style.setProperty('--x',(x)+'px');
    document.body.style.setProperty('--y',(y + document.documentElement.scrollTop)+'px');
}
```